# Original socket lib to asscess memcached under win7, but occured a error when to use 'set' command

Tags: python, sockets, memcached

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',11211))
cmd='%s %s %d %d %d\r\n%s' % ('set','a',0,0,5,'test')
s.sendall(cmd+'\r\n')
```

But memcached 1.2.6 server under win7 give a error:  CLIENT_ERROR bad data chunk
i don't know why. Other command like 'get' can work except the only 'set' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set` command in Memcache is used as follow:

```
set <key> <flags> <exptime> <bytes>
```

...followed by CRLF,the data, and again CRLF. In your case, your command expands to:

```
set a 0 0 5
```

...which means you are telling Memcache to expect 5 bytes of data, but then you send the data, `test`, which is only 4 bytes.